# What raster is needed for ArcMap pan-sharpening?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pansharpening

I have a "private" satellite image I would like to pansharpen in ArcMap. However, I cannot check the box in Symbology - Show - RGB Composite and in the Image Analysis window the symbol stay grey.

So I wondered if I might have the wrong tif?

What kind of TIFF is needed and how can I find out if I have the right one?

Or what else could be my problem?

Comment: Well, do you have an image to pansharpen "with"?

Comment: Official ArcGIS FAQ shows the process: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/fundamentals-of-panchromatic-sharpening.htm

Comment: @Erik Yes, I have a RGB Tif and a panchromatic Tif.

Comment: I am also aware of the ESRI description. There are two ways described: 1) Using the Pan-sharpen button on the Image Analysis window and 2) Applying pan-sharpening to a raster layer in ArcMap However, for possibility 1) The button stays grey and for 2) I can not check the checkbox. So my guess is that it is the wrong fromat of the Tif, but I am not sure if that is the problem.